# Read out the value of an <option> in a form and show a <div> with the same name

Tags: jquery, css, forms, html-select

I have a selectbox with some options.
Each option should, if selected, show a separate div.

Of course I could do it for every optionname/value like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form class="floatleft">
      <select size="1" id="stadtauswahl" name="Standortauswahl">
        <option value="" style="color: #666;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bitte wählen Sie&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
        <option value="/kontakt/hauptsitz/">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wiesbaden</option>
        <option value="/kontakt/berlin/">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Berlin</option>
        <option value="/kontakt/bad-harzburg/">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bad Harzburg</option>
        <option value="/kontakt/koeln/">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Köln</option>
        <option value="/kontakt/hamburg/">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hamburg</option>
        <option value="/kontakt/muenchen/">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;München</option>
        <option value="/kontakt/stuttgart/">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stuttgart</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#stadtauswahl').bind('change', function (e) { 
    if( $('#stadtauswahl').val() == '/kontakt/hauptsitz/') {
      $('#wiesbaden').slideToggle();
    }
    else{
      $('#wiesbaden').slideUp();
    }         
  });
});
```

**But** I want jQuery to read out the name and then select the div of the same name to show.

Comment: Can you make your question a bit clearer please? What DIV's do these need to be shown in? Are they dynamically created to or already in place?

Comment: Just updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TV9dY/1/

Comment: See my answer below....  http://jsfiddle.net/TV9dY/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code instead...

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#stadtauswahl').bind('change', function (e) { 
        $(this).find("option").each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase().split(" ").join("").trim();
            console.log("'" + text + "'");
            if ($(this).is(":selected")) {
                $('#' + text).slideDown();
            } else {
                $('#' + text).slideUp();
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

It will look for a div for each of the options (with all spaces removed from the text) and perform a `slideUp()` for all non-selected ones, and a `slideDown()` for the selected one.

**Note**

Ideally, you would give each of the divs to show/hide a class that you can use to hide them all and then it becomes easier to just show the one relevant one.  Also, unless there's a reason for having a path as the select value it would be better to use the div IDs as the values, so you don't have to rely on the text not having invalid characters in it (for IDs).

It may make more sense to have an array of objects that have a url parameter and a text parameter, and you hold the index of each of them in the select options.  This would mean you could simply look at the value of the selected option and use it to get all the associated info from the array.

Just options and thoughts - the above script will do what you ask though :)

Comment: It was the exact reason I suggested that this was a bad way to do it.  The text values are padded with spaces either side, as well as the id's being all lowercase.  I added a `toLowerCase()` and `trim()` and it works now.

Comment: Got it ;)Just replaced the variable text with value: http://jsfiddle.net/TV9dY/7/

Comment: In the example code he gave us value is a path, not the div id.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

jsFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/TV9dY/

**The JS:**

```
    $(document).ready( function() {

  $('#stadtauswahl').bind('change', function (e) {

    if( $('#stadtauswahl').find(":selected").text() != '') {

      $('#wiesbaden').slideToggle();
        $('#myDiv').remove();
$('#stadtauswahl').after('<div id="myDiv">' + $('#stadtauswahl').find(":selected").text() + '</div>');

    } else {

      $('#wiesbaden').slideUp();

    }         

  });

});
```

Not tested, but should work.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question correctly.  The divs already exist.  He wants to show the div that corresponds to the text of the selected option, not create a new div and show the text.

Comment: @Archer in that case, he could do with showing the DIV's each one maps to. Hmm. My bad. I read it too quickly.

Comment: I'm often guilty of the same :)

Comment: Yes Archer that is correct, sorry Michael maybe I haven't expressed myself correctly!